# ASP.NET MVC 3 Custom Type Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Right now, I have a class defined as such:

```
public class Task
{
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan? TimeRequired { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to allow the user to also enter "2h" or "15m" for 2 hours or 15 minutes respectively.  Is there a way I can allow these types of custom inputs?  I was thinking of just creating a text box and then doing a custom check against that incoming value and cast it correctly to a TimeSpan.  I wasn't sure if there was some type of "CustomConverter" much like the "CustomValidator" attribute.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I finally found it.  According to [Custom Model Binders](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/) you can just add a custom model binder in the Global.asax.  Here is what I did.  I added a class as such:

```
public class TimeSpanModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        string attemptedValue = value.AttemptedValue;

        // Custom parsing and return the TimeSpan? here.
    }
}
```

and then I added this line to my Global.asax.cs in `public void Application_Start()`

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeSpan?), new TimeSpanModelBinder());
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, I did a lot of searching before finding this answer.  I get the impression lots of people never need to bind a custom type.  Have you continued to use this approach?

Comment: I'm glad you found this useful!  I use it quite often as it allows custom inputs to be handled by a registered class rather than each time a model is used.  I've also used it against user Id's where I store the guid in a hidden variable in HTML and then add a custom model binder from Guid to my User object.  I'm sure there are many other possibilities.

Comment: This worked very well for me. I have a `struct` that unites two IDs to a string - for example: `a12:b35`. Using a ModelBinder is an easy way to populate the value. If anyone wonders how to achieve the opposite: the struct should override the `ToString` method. Then  `Url.Action("Test", new {id = new RecordId(12, 35)})` would work, for example. I'm not sure how to achieve that with a 3rd part type, like `TimeSpan?` in the question.